# localhost is not in the list of supported domains for this site key. recaptcha

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha, captcha, react-18

I have been trying to implement google reCaptcha v3 in my react form ,i am using next js and react 18 , but some how it shows an error like this "localhost is not in the list of supported domains for this site key. recaptcha" , and could't verify the captcha i hope some of my tech buddies can find this out , thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjlB.png)

i have tried to add localhost in my next config file , but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the domain in the [reCAPTCHA Admin Panel](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).